# Does the equality $(G^{der})^{ad}=G^{ad}$ always hold?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be an abstract or algebraic group, then ist it true that  $(G^{der})^{ad}=G^{ad}$? If yes, how does the proof go? If not, under what conditions is this true?